# How to open in(on) the current window?

Tags: c#, wpf

I think my question is simple but i can not handle with it.

If i have window and a button on it and i want to open other window control on that window how can i do that?
I try do that through the VSM but I jam and still don't know how to do that. Maybe there is a simplier way?

Yes. Thank all of you for answers, but I think i didn't specify clearly what i wanted to get.
Methods: Show() and ShowDialog() opens new windows and i wanted to open controls in current window.
I think about something like that:
   *newWindowControl nwc = new newWindowControl();

   LayoutRoot.Children.Add(nwc);*
but in **VSM**.
I don't know if it is possible to do that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open another window on top of existing window, just like a popup.. You can simply Initialize a new window and call its show method.

```
//Second window is of type Window
SecondWindow window = new SecondWindow();
window.Show();
```

Comment: Or use ShowDialog() for a modal window

Comment: ... and don't forget about Owner.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 form2 = new Form2())
    {
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```